# Безопасные способы компиляции Python в exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, auto-py-to-exe, nuitka

Всем доброго дня! Написали программу на Python и, чтобы скрыть библиотеки, которые мы использовали, пришлось прибегнуть к exe-файлу.

Пробовали pyinstaller - очень удобный способ, но слишком легко реверсится
Пробовали nuitka - очень безопасный способ, но на некоммерческой версии слишком мало функций. Из-за этого с использованием --standalone (чтобы python был включен в сборку, и пользователю не надо было скачивать его самостоятельно) создается папка с зависимостями python и exe-файл находится в ней вперемешку со всеми другими файлами (это не очень удобно для использования другими пользователями)

Прошу помочь ответить на вопросы:

Как предотвратить реверсинг exe-файла, скомпилированного через PyInstaller?
Можно ли обфусцировать скомпилированный exe-файл?
Есть ли другие безопасные способы компиляции?

Comment: Нет, просто пишите на компилируемом языке программирования, это намного лучше чем писать на Python

Comment: nuitka транслирует в Си, потом все компилируется. Но безопасных способов нет, exe файл в любом случае взломают, если будет нужно, даже если вы будете компилировать в машинный код, а не интерпретатор+байткод.

Comment: Безопасный способ - вообще не отдавать пользователю exe, а давать веб-приложение.